# Selecting data using psycopg2 from a schema based table in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, jinja2, psycopg2

I'm new to python and i have created a script to select the data from a schema based table in postgreSQL.

But whenever i'm running the script,getting the below error.Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

```
**Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL relation "public.sample" does not exist**
```

Below is the script i'm using,
i'm facing the below issues in this code.
    1. Cannot able to select from a table which is inside a schema(as mentioned above)
    2.There is a part to create a table in the script,even though it is running the TABLE is not getting created in the database.
   3.Also it will be very helpful if someone can guide me to create an HTML page using Jinja2(Currently the Data values are coming),inside the HTML script but have an doubt on how to do this for multiple users).

```
import psycopg2
import jinja2
from collections import namedtuple

TEMPLATE="""
     <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html><head><title>Jinja Template Example</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
       <style type="text/css">
       .container {max-width: 500px;padding-top: 100px;}</style></head>
       <body>
        <div class="container">
         <p>My string: {{my_string}}</p>
         <p>Value from the list:</p>
         <p>Loop through the list:</p>
         <ul>
           {% for row in rows %}
           <p style="line-height: 14px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;"> {{ row.column1 }}</p><br>
           {% endfor %}
         </ul>
        </div>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstr
          ap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          </body>
      </html>
      """

def dB_Fetch():
 try:
   connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="postgres",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="postgres")
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   print("Connection established")
   cursor.execute("select version()")
   version = cursor.fetchone()[0]
   print(version)
   cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cars")
   cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE cars(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255), price INT)")
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES('Audi', 52642)")
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES('Mercedes', 57127)")
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES('Skoda', 9000)")
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES('Volvo', 29000)")
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES('Bentley', 350000)")
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES('Volkswagen', 21600)")
   print("Table created")

   postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from public.Sample"
   cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
   print("Selecting rows from test table using cursor.fetchall")
   a = list();
   print("Print each row and it's columns values")


   env = jinja2.Environment()
   template = env.from_string(TEMPLATE)
   cursor.execute("SELECT Name FROM public.Sample;")

   row_tuple = namedtuple("Row", [col[0] for col in cursor.description])
   result = template.render(rows=[row_tuple(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()])
   print (TEMPLATE)
   print (result) 

 except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
     print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
 finally:
     if(connection):
         cursor.close()
         connection.close()
         print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dB_Fetch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the name of the schema and table

public.Sample does not exist in your databse.
Please check exact name of schema and table, also you can try without schema so it should automatically point to the public schema.